# Redirect URL using htaccess if it contains a directory and ends in php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect all URL's such as

```
 example.com/blog/product.php
```

to

```
 example.com/product.php
```

I.e. if the URL contains **/blog** and ends in .php I want to redirect to the URL with **/blog** removed.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Inside `/blog/.htaccess` you can have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^./]+)\.php$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

If `/blog/.htaccess` doesn't exist then in your root .htaccess you can have this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([^./]+)\.php$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /blog/(.*)\.php$ 
 RewriteRule ^.* /%1.php [R,L]
```